# Pricing and upgrading Azure shared websites to reserved mode

Tags: azure

I have two websites that are both running in shared mode in Windows Azure. I only want to update one of them to *Reserved Mode*, but unfortunately when I try to do so it says that it needs to upgrade all websites to Reserved Mode.

[image: Windows Azure Reserved mode]

This isn't really a problem, but my question is - will I get charged for one Reserved instance or two? Does it put both sites on one reserved instance? If so, how does this affect pricing?

Comment: I think this is off topic, because it doesn't have anything to do with programming. Isn't there an Azure support site run by Microsoft where you can ask?

Comment: Already looked and there doesn't seem to be anything on the windowsazure.com site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your shared websites will go under 1 Reserved instance thus you will be paying for just 1 reserved instance.